# PIG - Passing multiple words as a parameter

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In my PIG script I have the following:

```
REL = FILTER OLD_REL BY COL == '$filter';
```

If I pass $filter as a multi-word string `word1 word2`, PIG only filters against word1.  It is as if word2 is chopped off.

This happens when I do it from the command line or call it from oozie.

I'm using PIG 0.11.0-cdh4.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra single quotes to the string:

```
-p filter="'word1 word2'"
```

If you ever run into this type of problem again, it is useful to use the `-dryrun` option, which produces a script (text file) with substituted parameters, without executing the script.

Comment: Thanks that works.  @cabad, how do I deal with a single quote in the string?  Like if my string is "c'est bon"; I tried "'c'est bon'" and only end up with 'c'...